# Use "on the contrary" at the end of the sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

Can we use on the contrary at the end of the sentence?

My sentence is something like this:
To find out whether readers qualify Peter Pan as a good children literature or on the contrary.

Or can I just straight away end the sentence after "literature"?

Thank you for helping me! =)

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot use "on the contrary" in that sentence.

Remove the on  and you can - after fixing a few more issues. This could work as a sub-title

> **Investigating Pan**
>   To find out whether readers qualify Peter Pan as good children's literature or the contrary.

On the contrary is used as negation of something you stated:

> Some people consider Peter Pan poor literature. We, on the contrary, find the story really well written

And yes, you can just end the sentence after "literature"

Comment: I’d be tempted to go with: _To find out whether readers qualify Peter Pan as good children's literature or not._ Perhaps [or _otherwise_](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22or+otherwise%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) could be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

To augment mplungjan's good answer...

The prepositional phrase **on the contrary** goes with a *clause* and means "*opposing* the aforementioned statement".

> Some readers regard the work as great literature while, *on the
>   contrary*, **other readers do not (regard it as great literature).**

The noun-phrase **the contrary** goes with another noun-phrase and means "the *opposite* of the aformentioned thing".

> Is it **great literature** or *the contrary*?